# Add trailing slash to url only works with non-ww redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add a trailing slash to the url. It nearly works but there is a little problem i don't understand.

When i call the site http://domain.com/test > rewrite to www.domain.com > the trailing slash is added.

When i call the site directly http://www.domain.com/test > nothing is added.
Important to me is that https:// has to be redirected to https:// an not to http://

Here's my config:

```
############################################
```

### enable rewrites

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !price

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]   

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your rules with these simplified rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ http%1://www.domain.com/$1/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```